# How to extract each sentence from a text file using stanford-parser?

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I need to extract each sentence from a given text file and store that sentence in a String. I was using the lexparser-gui of the stanford-parser, the tool highlights each sentence of the given file. Is there a way, where I can use the stanford-parser.jar to do the sentence extraction in a java program? If yes, could anyone please give a sample demo on how to do it.

Thanks,
Sambhav

Comment: Do you have to use stanford-parser? There are other ways in the basic java library that you might be able to use.

Comment: @putty174  I don't have to use the parser. I am looking at ways which will help me extract sentences with most accuracy! Are you aware of anything else? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to extract the sentences from a text file, there's no need to use the parser. You can just take the regular sentence splitter, like so:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.setProperty("annotators","tokenize, ssplit");

    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    Annotation annotation = new Annotation("This is sentence one. This is sentence two.");
    pipeline.annotate(annotation);
    List<CoreMap> sentences = annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);
    for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {
        System.out.println(sentence);
    }
```